# Unable to resolve $GeoNear indices when using MongoDB + Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial, geocoding

I've spent a day in the mongo / mongoose docs and on stack overflow and can't seem to figure this one out.

**Here's my basic schema setup:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./config/config');
const db = mongoose.createConnection(config.uri, { autoIndex: false });

const storeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  location: { type:[Number], index:'2dsphere', required:true },
});

const Store = db.model('Store', storeSchema);
```

I have also tried:

```
const storeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  location: { type: { type: String }, coordinates: [Number] },
});

storeSchema.index({ location: "2dsphere" });
```

I set autoIndex to false on createConnection because [Mongoose automatically calls createIndex](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) on app start and the $geoNear query requires that there be only one index. I thought maybe Mongoose was creating a duplicate index, but this has not resolved the issue.

**I create a store record like this (simplified):**

```
const coordinates = { lng: -122.0266515, lat: 36.9743292 }

Store.create({
  name: "My Store", 
  location: [coordinates.lng, coordinates.lat], 
})
```

**This is my query that returns the error:**

```
const location = { longitude: -122.026423, latitude: 36.974538 } 
// above coordinates are near the 'My Store' record's coordinates.

const point = {
  type: "Point",
  coordinates: [location.longitude, location.latitude]  
}

Store.aggregate([{
  $geoNear: {
    near: point,
    distanceField: "dist.calculated",
    maxDistance: 100000,
    spherical: true                
    }
  }
])
.then((results) => console.log(results))
.catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

And here's the *"no geo indices for geoNear"* error that I'm getting:

```
{ MongoError: geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "no geo indices 
for geoNear", operationTime: Timestamp(1529989103, 8), $clusterTime: { 
clusterTime: Timestamp(1529989103, 8), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), keyId: 0 } } }
at queryCallback (/Users/`...`/node_modules/mongodb- 
core/lib/cursor.js:244:25)
at /Users/`...`/node_modules/mongodb- 
core/lib/connection/pool.js:544:18
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:150:11)
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "no geo indices for 
geoNear", operationTime: Timestamp(1529989103, 8), $clusterTime: { 
clusterTime: Timestamp(1529989103, 8), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), keyId: 0 } } }',
operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 8, high_: 
1529989103 },
ok: 0,
errmsg: 'geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "no geo indices for 
geoNear", operationTime: Timestamp(1529989103, 8), $clusterTime: { 
clusterTime: Timestamp(1529989103, 8), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), keyId: 0 } } }',
code: 16604,
codeName: 'Location16604',
'$clusterTime':
{ clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 8, high_: 
1529989103 },
`enter code here`signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] } } }
```

When I console.log *storeSchema.index()._indexes* I get the following:

```
[ [ { location: '2dsphere' }, {} ], [ {}, {} ] ]
```

...so the index appears to be there.

I've also tried calling ensureIndexes before running my query [after seeing the following stack overflow conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39842475/mongoerror-reports-no-indices-when-passed-indices-through-url-using-geonear).

```
Store.ensureIndexes({location: '2dsphere'})
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I found that the error actually has to do with the URI provided by MongoDB Atlas when I created my db instance.

Specifically the URI they provide (which I had copied and pasted) looks like this:

```
mongodb+srv://user:password@host.mongodb.net? 
readPreference=primaryPreferred&retryWrites=true
```

Removing "retryWrites=true" fixed this issue for me. More details available here:

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6109